# Create scrollable body section within a div

Tags: html

I have a div, which will be displayed in a popup using the jQuery dialog function.   The div contains a child div for header information, and second div for body information.

I want the body div to be scrollable so if the size of the body content extends outside of the dialog it is viewable by scrolling.

I sort of have this working by setting the height of the body div to 100% and with absolute positioning I set the bottom, left and right to 0px.  The problem is that the body div will the appear over top of the header div because I haven't set the top position.  I don't know the height of the header div.  Is there some way I can work this so the body div will appear below the header div without having to specify/know it's height?

Here's a jsfiddle example and html markup below:.

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wravqopx/)

```
<div>
  <div id="popup" style="width:200px;height:200px;position:absolute; z-index:999; background-color:blue">
    <div id="header" >
      controls<br />
      controls<br />
      controls<br />
    </div>
    <div id="body" style="height:100%;overflow-y:auto;position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px;">
      results<br />
      results<br />
      results<br />
      results<br />
      results<br />
      results<br />
      results<br />
      results<br />
      results<br />
      results<br />
      results<br />
      results<br />
      results<br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is js an option? You could always measure the `.header` on dom ready then set top value of `#body`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - js is an option.  I'm just currently unaware if this is possible simply with CSS. if it is that is definitely preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox to the rescue!

- Remove all styles from `#body`, except for `overflow-y: auto` (you want the element to follow the normal document flow, inside the popup div).
- Add `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` to `#popup` (for it to be a flexible container).
- Add `flex: 1` to `#body` (for it to stretch as needed).

```css
#popup
{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* just for readability: */
    color: #FFF;
    /* and all your previous styles */
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: blue;
}
#body
{
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
  <div id="header" >
    controls<br />
    controls<br />
    controls<br />
  </div>
  <div id="body">
    results<br />
    results<br />
    results<br />
    results<br />
    results<br />
    results<br />
    results<br />
    results<br />
    results<br />
    results<br />
    results<br />
    results<br />
    results<br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that this may not work in some outdated browsers, as [they lack flexbox support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), but it should work fine in what I consider any reasonably recent browser.

Comment: Oh that's fantastic!  I've still got to support IE8 though!  Now that I know about this option,  using IE8 is even more painful.

Comment: @Jeremy Since I don't have IE8 available, could you check whether [this horrible abomination](https://jsfiddle.net/Siguza/wravqopx/3/) works there? I'll add a detailed explanation to my post if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

in the css for the div try to add your own heigh like 100px than a % and then after than the overflow-y:auto; should work

Answer (score 0):

If you MUST have the height as variables, why not set the parent popup div to a certain width and height using viewport or px. Then display the child elements as block, then set their width using % to 100 (will calculate it off the parent div)?  This will ensure they take up the full width of the parent div, but be displayed sequentially in a vertical fashion. Then simply set overflow: auto;, or as Derby mentioned, overflow-y:auto.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    i= $("#header").height();
  n = $("#body").height();
  $("#body").height(n-i);
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wravqopx/4/